# Sonarqube 5.5 Impossible to Write to Binary Log

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-ops, sonarqube-5.5

When starting up SonarQube 5.5 for the first time we are getting the error below when it creates the tables in MySQL.  I see that maybe to get around this to use BINLOG_FORMAT = MIXED.  Is this a requirement?  Thank you.

```
ActiveRecord::JDBCError: Cannot execute statement: impossible to write to    
binary log since BINLOG_FORMAT = STATEMENT and at least one table uses a  
storage engine limited to row-based logging. InnoDB is limited to row-logging 
when transaction isolation level is READ COMMITTED or READ UNCOMMITTED.: 
INSERT INTO schema_migrations (version) VALUES ('710')
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the replication mode is enabled, the binary_log must be compatible with the row based replication (rows or mixed).

Comment: Thank you Eric.  Is there a way to change the transaction isolation in Sonar from READ COMMITTED which uses row-based logging to REPEATABLE READ which uses statement logging?  I see in the early version of Sonarqube that you were able to switch between different transaction isoations but couldn't find anything for version 5.5.  Thanks again.